# XSLT2 multiple replace in tranform string

Tags: xml, xslt

I use the XSLT (V2) Replace function. I want to replace multiple strings. Two strings are working, how can I replace more than two strings. I would just like extend the list in the current node:

```
<xsl:value-of select=" replace(replace(.,'\\n',''), .,'.p..nbsp...p.','')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Tried different combinations with brackets and commas but nothing seems to work. Can't find a proper syntax.

Comment: Please state clearly what do you want to replace with what and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you have many find/replace pairs, you may find it more convenient to construct a dictionary as shown in this example:

**XML**

```
<input>Mary had a color object, it was quite size and reminded us of a shape.</input>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="dictionary">
    <entry find="object">lamb</entry>
    <entry find="color">white</entry>
    <entry find="shape">circle</entry>
    <entry find="size">large</entry>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="dict" match="entry" use="@find" />

<xsl:template match="input">
    <output>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{string-join($dictionary/entry/@find, '|')}" >
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('dict', ., $dictionary)"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>Mary had a white lamb, it was quite large and reminded us of a circle.</output>
```

---

### Caution:

Whenever you have multiple find/replace pairs, you may encounter a problem of pairs colliding with each other. There are two types  of collision that need to be considered:

1. A *searchString* of one pair contains the *searchString* of another pair;
2. A *replaceString* of one pair contains the *searchString* of another pair.

The two methods of performing the replacements - nested `replace()` functions vs. `xsl:analyze-string` differ in how they will be affected by these collisions.

---

**1. A *searchString* of one pair contains the *searchString* of another pair:**

Input string:

```
you are young
```

| Find | Replace |
| --- | --- |
| you | we |
| young | old |

Here, both methods will return:

```
we are weng
```

instead of the expected:

```
we are old
```

and the solution is the same for both: change the order of the find/replace pairs so that the longer *searchStrings* come before the shorter ones.

---

**2. A *replaceString* of one pair contains the *searchString* of another pair:**

Input string:

```
John is red
```

| Find | Replace |
| --- | --- |
| John | Fred |
| red | blue |

The `xsl:analyze-string` method is unaffected by this collision.

However, the nested `replace()` method will return:

```
Fblue is blue
```

instead of the expected:

```
Fred is blue
```

Changing the order of the replacements will again solve the problem in this case; however determining the correct order is not as easy as before. Ultimately, the only safe solution I can think of is using intermediate values:

| Find | Replace |
| --- | --- |
| John | «John» |
| red | «red» |
| «John» | Fred |
| «red» | blue |

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself:

```
<xsl:value-of select=" replace(replace(replace(.,'String#1','Replace#1'),'String#2','Replace#2'), 'String#3','Replace#3')" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Comment: Note that in XSLT 3.0 you can write `replace(., 'x', 'y') => replace('p','q') => replace('a','b')` which is rather more legible.

Comment: Note the caution about collisions I have added to my answer.